# What determines the path where the system searches for a file?

Tags: bash, executable

I am trying to get [npm](http://npmjs.org/) to work. In the process, I seem to have two versions of it installed: A corrupt one installed in ~/bin, and another I just compiled and ran `make install` to put it in `/usr/local/bin/npm`.

So, I moved the entire ~/bin folder into ~/old/bin ... but still when I run `npm` the system searches in ~/bin:

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
$ alias npm
-bash: alias: npm: not found
$ npm
-bash: /home/ubuntu/bin/npm: No such file or directory
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
$
```

What causes Ubuntu to look for npm in `~/bin/npm` ? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. I don't know if the question is ubuntu-specific or not, it can be moved to askubuntu if needed.

I do see ~/bin in the PATH, but as far I as understand this only means that if npm was present at ~/bin then it would have used it ... but why does bash insist to look for it specifically there? Why doesn't it find `/usr/local/bin/npm`, even though the `which` command does find it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The executable's previously known location is likely hashed by the shell. Resetting the shell's cache with `hash -r` should fix the issue.

If you don't want to reset the entire cache, you can delete the individual entry for `npm` using `hash -d npm`.

Comment: Excellent. Any reference to `hash` you can refer me to for further reading? Googling for linux hash does't seem to point me the right way.

Comment: @ripper234 - `hash` is a shell builtin command. The bash manpage holds more detail.

Comment: @ripper234 `help hash` also contains some good information.

Comment: Urk!  I can't believe that in 2012 we are still using shells that require to be rehashed when the $PATH changes.  I wonder if there is a bash option to require it to rehash at every command?

Comment: @NormanRamsey - You could put `hash -r` in your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` I guess.

Comment: @ChrisDown: luckily for me I use `ksh`, which "just works" :-)

Comment: @NormanRamsey - Actually, many `ksh` implementations have the same caching functionality enabled, and provide `rehash` as the equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisDown there is only one `ksh` and it is the true shell from the hand of David Korn.  I have never found an imitation worth using.  And `ksh` has not required `rehash` nonsense since ksh88i.

Comment: Does it still clobber the history file (close multiple xterms -> only the last one's history gets saved)?

Comment: @XTL Does *what* clobber the history file?

Comment: @ChrisDown ksh. I used them a lot, but that was one of the top reasons I dumped it on my desktops.

Comment: @XTL Er, that's a bit offtopic for this answer...

Comment: Well, it had gone way down that path already :)